# Defining computed observables on members of child array using Knockout mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have the following:

```
// Child Array is Cards, trying to add computed observable for each child
var CardViewModel = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    this.editing = ko.observable(false); 
};

var mapping = {  
    'cards': {  // This never gets hit, UNLESS I remove the 'create' method below
        create: function (options) {
            debugger;
            return new CardViewModel(options.data);
        }
    },

    create: function(options) {
        var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
        innerModel.cardCount = ko.computed(function () {
            return innerModel.cards().length;
        });
        return innerModel;
    }
};

var SetViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(setData, mapping);
debugger;
ko.applyBindings(SetViewModel);
```

However I can't get the 'cards' binding to work - that code isn't reached unless I remove the 'create' method.  I'm trying to follow the example from the knockout site:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

They do this for the child object definition:

```
var mapping = {
    'children': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new myChildModel(options.data);
        }
    }
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

With the ChildModel defined like this:

```
var myChildModel = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.nameLength = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.name().length;
    }, this);
}
```

I've spent the past day on this and cannot for the life of me figure out why this isn't working.  Any tips would be awesome.

EDIT: Here's a fiddle of what I'm working with.  It's only showing SIDE 1 in the result because "editing" isn't recognized here:

```
<div data-bind="visible: !$parent.editing()" class="span5 side-study-box">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/1/

This is the error I get in chrome when I run it:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: TypeError: Object
>    has no method 'editing'; Bindings value: visible: !$parent.editing()

Comment: can you put up fiddle so its easy for us?

Comment: Just added one, thanks Ash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overridden the `create` behavior for your view model.  The mapping plugin will not call any of the other handlers for the properties for you.  Since you're mapping from within the `create` method, move your `cards` handler in there.

```
var mapping = {  
    create: function(options) {
        var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {
            'cards': {
                create: function (options) {
                    debugger;
                    return new CardViewModel(options.data);
                }
            }
        });
        innerModel.cardCount = ko.computed(function () {
            return innerModel.cards().length;
        });
        return innerModel;
    }
};
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/7/)

Comment: Wow, thanks Jeff.  Such a simple solution.  One more question if you don't mind - with the cardCount method, should I be using innerModel.cards(), or this.cards()?

Comment: Well you wouldn't be able to use `this` because you haven't passed in your `innerModel` as the second argument. If you did, then you could use `this`.

Answer (score -1):

you didnt needed to have parenthesis. I just changed from

```
!$parent.editing() 

 to 


!$parent.editing
```

See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/6/)

Comment: It would be wrong to make that change.  The `editing` observable was never created so trying to get the value from it (by calling it) fails. Your proposed change changes the logic from "visible if the card is not being edited" to "visible if the editing observable is not defined" which is incorrect.

Comment: @JeffMercado yes agree. Thanks for your explaination.

Comment: knockout is knocking me out...  thanks again for the help guys

Comment: p.s., it would be fine if the `!` was not in there. If the expression was just returning an observable, then knockout would automatically unwrap the value.